# Process URL in CGI script

Tags: perl, cgi

```
read(STDIN, $FormData, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
@pairs = split(/&/, $FormData);                              
foreach $pair (@pairs) {

(name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);          
$value =~ tr/+/ /;

$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

$FORM{$name} = $value;
    my $Var1 = $Form{Var1};
    my $Var2 = $Form{Var2};}
```

I need help in Perl object oriented script modification, which processes
the submitted data from URL, calls LDAP and get user parameters, adds these
parameters to POST form and send http POST with all data to the same URL.

My goal is to modify the original Perl script to take multiple articles parameters. 
Multiple articles parameters will be in the form:

```
id0=7kqm0uoamdtkff548567abdi3a&qpw0=ATYP%2d.....
&id1=7kqm0uoamdtcccccckff54123abdfn5&qpw1=ATYP....
........
&idN=NXXXXXX&qpwN=ATYP%2d%201....
```

Where N <= 50

I've read the standard input (sent by the form)

I can't figure out how the new parameters:

```
idN    where N <= 50
qpwN   where N <= 50
```

can be added to the associative array `%names`

I've parsed the "^id" from the keys:

```
my $key;
my $count;
foreach $key (sort keys(%names)) {
if ($key =~ '^id') {
   print $key, '=', $names{$key}, "\n";
   $count++;
   }
}
print "Total articles number = $count\n";

if ($count <= 50) {
print "You ordered $count articles\n";
}
else {

print "You exceeded the 50 articles limit"
}
```

So I want to add two new parameters `$idN` & `$qpwN`
where N <= 50 in this kind of form:

```
my $Var1 = $Form{Var1};
my $Var2 = $Form{Var2};
```

How can it be performed?
Thank you in advance!

Esther

Comment: The [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm/lib/CGI.pm) Perl module (which is in the Perl core, at least for the time being) has already implemented most of what you're doing here, and better. Learn to use it.

Comment: I've used the following modules in my script:

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use CGI;
use Net::LDAP;

use Encode qw(decode);
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

Comment: I don't see you actually **using** it in your script, though! You're still trying to read and parse POST parameters manually, which is crazy. Create a CGI object and use `$q->param`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be playing with $q->param

Answer (score 3):

If you are processing data from a form in a Perl script, use CGI.pm and [CGI::Expand](http://search.cpan.org/~bowmanbs/CGI-Expand-2.03/Expand.pm) to handle advanced query parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Expand;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $p = CGI::Expand->expand_cgi($q);
```

$p will then contain all of your query parameters.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't use the  CGI::Expand module. I'll read the documentation.

Comment: Again thank you very much! I's exactly what I was looking for